# Create Partial view in angular to show data

Tags: html, angular

Let me start by saying that this is the first time I've tried my hand at Angular and many concepts are not very clear to me, but I'm trying to understand

I have this view:

```
<div class="main-container" *arLoading="loading">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-title" ngClass.lt-md="mobile-content-title"><h2>VIEWING AND ACCEPTING THE QUESTIONNAIRE</h2></div>
    <div class="inner-content">

      <ng-container>
        <p>Enter your personal code to view the questionnaire</p>
        <form fxLayout="column"
              #formcontrol="ngForm"
              [formGroup]="form"
              (ngSubmit)="verifyCode()">
          <div fxLayout="row">
            <mat-form-field fxFlex>
              <input matInput
                     formControlName="code"
                     placeholder="Personal code"
                     required />
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </form>
        <br />
        <div fxLayout="row">
          <mat-label fxFlex="100">Questions and answers</mat-label>
          <div *ngFor="let request of questionnaireToView.requests">
            <!--start--><mat-label fxFlex="100">{{ request.text }}:{{ request.description }}</mat-label>
            <div *ngFor="let answer of request.risposte">
              <mat-label fxFlex="100">{{answer.description}}</mat-label>
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let complementaryQuestion of request.complementaryQuestions">
              <!--Here I should repeat the lines in a loop or those commented between start and end-->
            </div><!--end-->
          <p>
            <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="acceptance">
              <mat-radio-button value="true" checked style="margin-right: 10px;">The answers are correct, I accept</mat-radio-button>
              <mat-radio-button value="false">The answers are incorrect, I refuse</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
          </p>
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
            <button class="ar-button" type="button" fxFlex="10" fxFlex.xs="100" fxFlex.sm="100" (click)="confirmAcceptance()" mat-flat-button>Confirm</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I were faced with a project in asp.net mvc and cshtml file, I would put everything in a partial, in the last loop I would call it, is something similar possible in Angular?